# Child elements getting clipped in SVG when using Firefox or Edge but works fine in Chrome

Tags: svg

By no means am I an SVG expert, but I cannot figure out why this fairly simple element is not rendering correctly in Firefox or Edge but works fine in Chrome.

In FF and Edge the text gets cropped because it seems to be positioning incorrectly.

```
<svg id="view" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
    <g transform="scale(1)">
        <text fill="#000000" id="val" font-size="50px" x="0" y="15" anchor="start" font-family="Arial" style="font-weight:bold;" alignment-baseline="hanging">Sample Text</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vz13tLod/

Comment: Don't use [alignment-baseline="hanging"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/alignment-baseline#Browser_Compatibility) and change the y value to what you need.

Comment: Enxaneta's answer in the comments works.